# General equation of a wave

Tags: waves, speed

My book says that functions which represent a wave motions satisfy the differential equation :

$$ \frac{\partial^2 y}  {\partial^2t} = v^2 \frac{\partial^2 y}  {\partial^2x} $$

where $v$ is the velocity of the wave.

But I don't understand its physical reason.

As a side question, I just wanted some intuition for the formula for the speed of the wave on a string i.e. : $ v = \sqrt{ T/m}$ Like why should it hold true, its physical reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing coordinates $u= x+vt$ $w= x-vt$ the written equation transforms to
$$\frac{\partial^2 y }{\partial u \partial w}=0\tag{1}\:.$$
Assuming that $(t,x)$ ranges in the whole $\mathbb R^2$ that is equivalent to say that $(u,w)$ ranges in the same set, the solutions of (1) can easily showed to be all the function of the form
$$y(u,w) = f(u) + g(w)\:.$$
Coming back to the initial variables we have:
$$y(t,x)= f(x+ vt) + g(x-vt)\:.$$
The physical meaning of that solution is evident. Varying $t$, the first function $f(x+vt)$ describes a *rigid translation*, from the right to the left, of the profile $y=f(x)$, with constant *velocity* $v>0$. Similarly, varying $t$, the second function $g(x-vt)$ describes a *rigid translation* from the left to the right of the profile $y=g(x)$, with constant *velocity* $v>0$.

Concerning your last question, a careful analysis just based on "F=ma" applied to a small portion of a string with linear mass density $m$ and tension $T$,  establishes that, for small deformations along the vertical axis (in comparison with the deformation along the horizontal axis), the profile of the string evolves with the mentioned equation.

**ADDENDUM**. I have some spare time before my lecture, so I can complete the last part of my answer. Consider the string described by $y=y(x)$ and a small portion of string of endpoints $x$ and $x+d$. If the vertical slope is small with respect to $d$, the mass of the portion is approximatively $md$, where $m$ is the constant linear density mass of the string. Along the vertical direction, the equation of motion of the portion is, assuming the tension $T$ remaining constant in absolute value (but with different directions at different points):
$$m d\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}|_{x'} = T \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}|_{x+d} -  T \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}|_{x}\:.\tag{1}$$
Above $x'$ is the middle point of the portion, $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \tan \alpha(x)$ is the slope of the string at the generic point  $x$. The net force on the portion is due to the tension vector acting at the two endpoints and pulling them towards opposite directions with different slopes. The projection of the *tension vector* along $y$ (that vector is always tangent to the string) should be $T \sin \alpha(x)$, however, for small slopes $\tan \alpha = \sin \alpha$ and the identity 
$$T \sin \alpha(x) = T \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$$
 is approximatively true. If $d$ is small, (1) can be rewritten as
$$m d\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}|_x = T \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}|_xd$$
that is 
$$\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} = \frac{T}{m} \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}\:.$$
This is the wanted equation.